# CruiseControl.net - CCNetUser property empty

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Looking at a recent build log I noticed the CCNetUser property is set to empty, should it not be the user who has requested the build?

```
<cruisecontrol project="...">
    <parameters>
        ....
        <parameter name="$CCNetUser" value="" />
```

I want the username of the person who's just requested a force build so that I can send them an e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CNetUser property can be empty if it's not a force build. If the build is triggered by a source control/project trigger then the property is empty.
If the build is forced via the dashboard and not cctray the property may be empty too.

Comment: When is that property not empty?

Comment: When you force a build from CCTray. This property represent the windows account that requested the build in this case.

Comment: The documentation says : "The user who forced the build. If security is off, or the build is not forced, then this will not be set" see the end of http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Executable%20Task.html